# Android Studio - Importing Simple-Xml library

Tags: android, xml, maven, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am going crazy with my Android Studio IDE.

I am willing to add the Maven library simple-xml from Central (v2.7.1)

1. The project compiles well
2. Gradle has the lib dependency in its `build.gradle`:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
     compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
   }
   ```
3. Export is checked in Android Studio's Module Settings for the simple-xml lib:

Screenshot here: https://s6.postimg.cc/xxgj56zkx/Module_Settings.png

And I got the Class not found when I run my app ...

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister

I am lost, It sounds like Gradle doesn't pack the lib and dependencies in the apk for some reasons ...

**Edit1**: my Android Studio version is 0.2.13 (latest), Gradle 0.5.+

**Edit2**: full build.gradle I use

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
}
```

Comment: cf my Edit 2 for the full build.gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was the graddle plugin 0.5.+ as I expected.

The Android Studio 0.3.0 with gradle plugin 0.6.+ (Gradle 1.8) now fixes the problem.

However, I made the application to work with the Android Studio 0.2.13 and gradle plugin 0.5 this way:

As the gradle plugin refuses to deploy the library from maven central, I downloaded the library and dependencies to the lib directory of my project.
I setup the project to use the library as a local one in the lib directory of the project.

Directions for the workaround:

1. remove all references in my project to simple-xml (maven central) in Module Settings
2. Copy simple-xml-2.7.1.jar, stax-1.2.0.jar, stax-api-1.0.1.jar and xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar to  lib directory in my project
3. Select the lib simple-xml-2.7.1.jar in my project and Import the lib using Add as Library contextual menu
4. Change the build.gradle like this:

   dependencies {

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'

   compile files('simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')
   ```

   }

Note: do not include the dependencies, otherwise they will create conflicts with the Android system as mentionned by Grzegorz

Answer (score 56):

You should add `simple-xml` library this way:

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Libraries `stax-api` and `xpp3` are conflicting with Android classes. The classes from these jars seem to be included in Android.

Original `dex` message was:

> trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.

Comment: You are right for the dependencies exclusion. I needed to exclude the libraries in my build.gradle. This workaround worked only when I was using the simple-xml library downloaded in the local directory lib of my project .... sadly

Comment: Just started seeing this issue when updating to gradle 0.12.2.  This recommendation works like a charm.

Comment: Brilliant :)   I was getting a error with **Trouble Processing “javax/xml/XMLConstants.class”** and the xpp3 conflicts. Took ages to find this answer, but alll is working great now. Thanks :)

Comment: after 4 years, this comment is still saving asses. thanks!

Comment: For some reason, I tried adding this in my gradle.build file, but it didn't changed. Maybe more modules from the simple-xml jar are now included in newer Android API versions. Or gradle lint, is more sensitive ? Still stuck in error when I run gradle:build, anyone facing this issue too?

Comment: Even after 8 years, still the answer is useful and still conflicts exist.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error using maven with Android. I corrected dependency and everything worked well. It's my dependency for simple-xml library:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
<version>2.7.1</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Helps me a lot! Thank you!