# Gradle dependency exclusion

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've a project A and a project B. Project A is a **core** project used by other projects too. Here's his `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455878/1423773
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5'
}
```

Since it's a **core** project having the latest dependencies versions makes sense. Project B uses a dependency that uses `httpcore-4.2.4.jar` and it will throw a duplicate dependency error if I don't modify my **core** project `build.gradle` to:

```
dependencies {
    ...    
//    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5') {
        exclude module: 'httpcore'
    }
}
```

And this is something I would like to avoid because I don't want to change my core project `build.gradle`.
What's the best solution for this situation? If I removed/exclude the `.jar` from my other dependency would work? If so, how can I remove it? I've tried `exclude module/group` but without any luck. Something I was thinking of was [Chapter 56. Multi-project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) (I haven't read yet) but I would like to avoid having different `gradle.build` files in my core project for every non-core project.

My project B conflict dependency: [co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.40](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/co.realtime/messaging-android/2.1.40)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, It was in front of me all the time...

So inside my project B I just have to follow the same approach I used in my **core** project:

```
compile (project(':submodules:MyCoreProject')){
        exclude module: 'httpcore'
        //co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.40
        //uses 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'
}
```

and now my **core** project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455878/1423773
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5'
}
```